# State not referenced as I expect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

While trying to build a React Component that renders a list of objects I ran into some behaviour that I cannot explain.

I use the `useState` hook to keep track of a list of animals.
When I click the button 'add animal', I add an object to that list containing a random animal.
I do this several times.

...so far so good, an object is created and added every time, and my `animalList` is properly rendered.

*But here is where I get lost;*

When I click the 'Remove' button on an Animal component it logs the `animalList` to the console, but it shows a different value for every item in the list, while *I expect it to be the same* for all of them.

It appears that the value of `animalList` is equal to what it was at the time the object was created rather than referencing the state.

My next step would be to remove the clicked object, but they don't seem to share the same reference to the list.

Can somebody *help me understand* what is happening here? I have added the code required to recreate the issue:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

export default function App() {
  const [animalList, updateAnimalList] = useState([]);

  const animals = [
    {name: 'anaconda'}, {name: 'brachiosaurus'}, {name: 'chimpansee'}, {name: 'dragon'}, {name: 'eagle'}, {name: 'fox'},
    {name: 'giraffe'}, {name: 'hellhound'}, {name: 'iguana'}, {name: 'jackal'}, {name: 'koala'}, {name: 'lion'},
    {name: 'meerkat'}, {name: 'nyan-cat'}, {name: 'ostrich'}, {name: 'pterodactyl'}, {name: 'quail'}, {name: 'rhinoceros'},
    {name: 'sfinx'}, {name: 'triceratops'}, {name: 'unicorn'}, {name: 'vampire deer'}, {name: 'whale'}, {name: 'xiao'},
    {name: 'yoghurt'}, {name: 'zebra'},
  ];

  const addAnimal = () => {
    updateAnimalList([...animalList,
      { ...animals[Math.floor(Math.random() * animals.length)],
        onClick: removeAnimal,
      }
    ]);
  }

  const removeAnimal = () => {
    console.log(animalList);
    // let newArray = [...animalList];
    //newArray.splice(index, 1);
    //updateAnimalList(animalList);
  };

  return (
    <div className="app">

        <button onClick={addAnimal}>addAnimal</button>
        { animalList.map( (animal, index) => {
          return (
            <Animal key={index} {...animal} />
          )
        })}

    </div>
  );
};

export function Animal(animal) {
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <h2>{ animal.name }</h2>
      <button onClick={animal.onClick}>Remove</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I intend to pass an index as a parameter to the ```removeAnimal``` function, but I removed it from the example because it seemed irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Pass function reference directly. Do not save it in state. That will fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid storing `onClick` in `animalList` because `removeAnimal` captures a stale reference to a version of `animalList`.

`updateAnimalList` can be used like you did or it can also accept an updater function which receives the current value of `animalList`.

So by combining these two, I would end up with something like this:

```js
const animals = [
  // the animals (should be defined outside of the component as it is not changing)
];

export default function App() {
  const [animalList, updateAnimalList] = useState([]);

  const addAnimal = () => {
    updateAnimalList([
      ...animalList,
      animals[Math.floor(Math.random() * animals.length)]
    ]);
  }

  const makeRemoveAnimal = (index) => () => {
    updateAnimalList((current) => [...current].splice(index, 1))
  };

  return (
    <div className="app">

        <button onClick={addAnimal}>addAnimal</button>
        {animalList.map((animalName, index) => {
          return (
            <Animal key={index} name={animalName} onClick={makeRemoveAnimal(index)} />
          )
        })}

    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I would not use index as key though

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I find the concept of 'stale reference' a bit difficult to grasp still, but it makes a bit more sense now.

It appears that using an updater function alone also works (at least for referencing the state).

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava I left it as is but I agree

Answer (score 2):

Because every time you add an animal here:

```
 { ...animals[Math.floor(Math.random() * animals.length)],
        onClick: removeAnimal,
 }
```

you are also storing a function reference (`removeAnimal`) in the state.

The *version* of `removeAnimal` which you are storing is *from the render when the click happened* (aka stale closure). Hence, inside `removeAnimal`:

```
let newArray = [...animalList];
```

the `animalList` is also *from the render when the click happened*.

No reason to store `removeAnimal` on each click inside array. Just declare it as function and pass an id of object you want to delete. Then  you can always use *that* single function.

Also you seem to be using index as key which is [not recommended](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys-must-only-be-unique-among-siblings) **especially if array items may reorder**. Use some id instead.

So you could do:

```
{
  animalList.map((animal) => {
    return (
      <Animal
        key={animal.id}
        {...animal}
        onClick={() => removeAnimal(animal.id)}
      />
    );
  });
}
```

Then

```
const removeAnimal = (id) => {
  updateAnimalList(animalList.filter((x) => x.id != id));
};
```

Answer (score -1):

It is not good to store link `onClick` in `animalList` because link becomes unactual.

It looks like you should send `name` of animal. When you will send `name` of animal, then it would be pretty simple to remove item of array:

```
// you need to send here name of animal  
const removeAnimal = () => {
    const updatedArray = animalList.filter( p=> p.name !== 'anaconda')
    updateAnimalList(prevAnimals => [...updatedArray]);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get the same function with useRef

const [animalList, updateAnimalList] = useState([]);

```
  const refRemoveFunction = useRef(() => {});

  const addAnimal = () => {
    updateAnimalList([
      ...animalList,
      {
        ...animals[Math.floor(Math.random() * animals.length)],
        onClick: refRemoveFunction
      }
    ]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    refRemoveFunction.current = (index) => {
      animalList.splice(index, 1);
      updateAnimalList([...animalList]);
    };
  }, [animalList]);
```

And you can use like this:

```
export function Animal(animal) {
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <h2>{animal.name}</h2>
      <button onClick={() => animal.onClick.current(animal.index)}>Remove</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I hope, It will be useful for you.